# left join with group by and sum in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert T-sql which is

```
select c.description, sum(t.quantity), sum(t.Price) from trn_itm t
left join CAFE c on t.Item_key = c.dfm_key
where transaction_key = 87378
group by c.Description
```

my linq is

```
var query = from p in DfmSession.CurrentContext.TRN_ITMs
            join c in DfmSession.CurrentContext.CAFEs on p.Item_key equals c.Dfm_key into t
            from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where p.Transaction_key == _dfmkey
            select new
            {
                Dfm_key = (int?)rt.Dfm_key,
                rt.Description,
                p.Quantity,
                p.Price
            };
```

How do I get Sum(p.Quantity) and Sum(p.Price)?

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from p in DfmSession.CurrentContext.TRN_ITMs
            join c in DfmSession.CurrentContext.CAFEs on p.Item_key equals c.Dfm_key into t
            from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where p.Transaction_key == _dfmkey
            group p by rt.Description into g
            select new
            {
                Description = g.Keu
                Quantity = g.Select(x => x.Quantity).Sum()
                Price = g.Select(x => x.Price).Sum()
            };
```

Comment: Did u mean Description = g.Key, Quantity = g.Sum(x=>x.Quantity), Price = g.Sum(x=>x.Price)

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from p in DfmSession.CurrentContext.TRN_ITMs
        join c in DfmSession.CurrentContext.CAFEs on p.Item_key equals c.Dfm_key into t
        from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where p.Transaction_key == _dfmkey
        group by rt.Description into g
        select new
     {
         description = g.Key,
         Price = g.Sum(x => x.Price),
         Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
     };
```

Comment: I am getting error on group by. The message I am getting is Cannot convert lambda expression to type System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 0):

```
group by rt.Description into g
```

and then use aggregate functions of your choice on `g`, e.g.:

```
select new { Price = g.Sum(x => x.Price) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
group by su.Description into h
```

and then use aggregate methods of your choice on h, e.g.:

```
select new { Price = h.Sum(y =? y.Price) }
```